# Rails loading wrong version of Ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

For some reason Rails is loading an older version of Ruby which all is a little odd (since all other indicators say otherwise).

Here's the version outputs from all the usual commands:

```
# Ruby Version
# $ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-linux]

# Rails Version
# $ rails -v
Rails 3.2.6

# Gem Console
# $ gem environment
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.23
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.3 (2012-04-20 patchlevel 194) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /usr/local/ruby/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/local/ruby/1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/ruby/1.9.3-p194/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /usr/local/ruby/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
     - /home/vagrant/.gem/ruby/1.9.1
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/    

# IRB
# $ irb
irb(main):001:0> RUBY_VERSION
=> "1.9.3"

# Rails Console
# $ rails console
Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.6)
irb(main):002:0> RUBY_VERSION
=> "1.8.7"
```

Note that only Rails is reporting the wrong version while all others are reporting 1.9.3.

I installed Ruby using the gem environment listed above, so would have expected it to be operating differently...

Any ideas?

Comment: What does `which rails` show?

Comment: `which rails` returns `/usr/local/ruby/1.9.3-p194/bin/rails`

Comment: Odd. Okay, try `head -1 \`which rails\``.

Comment: returned `#!/usr/local/ruby/1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby`

Comment: Well that is strange. I thought perhaps your Rails gem install had got mixed up somehow, but it doesn’t look like it.

Comment: I thought the same, it's a little odd. The whole OS is saying 1.9.3, but Rails (whether it's a system gem or installed through bundler) insists 1.8.7.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using RVM or rbenv both have a project level dotfile (.rbenv, .rvm) that can play havoc with stuff like this.  Check there first.

Comment: I'm not using either on this machine (it's soon to be a production box) and i've found both to cause far too much trouble. (talk bout ironic).